# How to store a single int value in kernel?

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I'm writing a netfilter module and need to store current time value somewhere inside the module to calculate difference in time. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: This is ill-formed, it's too wide open, and there's no code showing your attempt.

Comment: What do you have so far? You have some module, or it is a theoretical question ? If you have a module, you probably should have your own `struct  my_device` describing your device, there you should keep all relevant data, for example your current time. An instance of the struct might be global (bad practice), or inside your `struct  my_device` will be instance of `cdev` for example, and you will obtain your `mydevice` via `container_of` macro

Comment: Please try to make your questions more understandable ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understood your question properly. Because you are not provided any piece of code. Any way you can keep your variable either in
 **device structure of  module**, or you can declare variable simply as a **Global variable**.